# Welcoming 2019 Pi day: How to draw the letter π?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, tikzducks, picture-mode, tikzlings

**First of all:** don't forget that exactly 140 years ago, [Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) was born; but exactly one year ago, [Stephen William Hawking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking) passed away. What a special day for science!

---

> #### Question
>
> How to *draw* the letter π **not** in the standard way (i.e. `\pi`)?

I mean "draw", not "type"! Today there will be no `\pi`, but there will be something like this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2)--(3,2);
\draw (1,0)--(1,2);
\draw (2,0)--(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(inspired by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) – I draw this in Ti*k*Z just because I don't know how to use `picture` ;))

Or this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck
\duck[xshift=1cm,yshift=2cm]
\duck[xshift=1cm,yshift=4cm]
\duck[xshift=1cm,yshift=6cm]
\duck[xshift=0cm,yshift=8cm]
\duck[xshift=-2cm,yshift=7.5cm]
\duck[xshift=2cm,yshift=8cm]
\duck[xshift=4cm,yshift=8cm]
\duck[xshift=6cm,yshift=8cm]
\duck[xshift=8cm,yshift=8cm]
\duck[xshift=5cm,yshift=6cm]
\duck[xshift=5cm,yshift=4cm]
\duck[xshift=5.5cm,yshift=2cm]
\duck[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=0cm]
\duck[xshift=8cm,yshift=1cm]
\node[font=\huge] at (4,11) {Happy $\pi$ day with \verb|tikzducks|!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

They are my proudest π drawings, and as today is Pi day, I'd like to see yours!

---

*Well, why didn't I delay the time of asking the question by 8 minutes? I asked this at 1:51:31 UTC time, and the "Pi second" of this year is at 1:59:26 today!*

Comment: @user49915 I don't think we can have the output and the code being exactly the same :))

Comment: JouleV are you saying @user49915 "can't have his pi and use it" look at all the other "typos" for answers :-)

Comment: @KJO No. Just look at the C code. It is compilable -- it is like a perfect Codegolf answer for a TeX.SE question :) I don't think we can have the same thing with LaTeX: the code is compilable and it fits to a pi shape!

Comment: @user49915 Btw if 49915 is not a special number for you, I think you should be user165772 :) [user49915](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/49915) is no longer here anymore.

Comment: @user49915 well, I need an old compiler at least, I would guess.  Any details on the requirements?

Comment: @JouleV as a result of your comment I have changed avatar It is not quite a pi Codegolf answer but it `\includes` itself (almost)

Comment: @Rahul Sorry for my poor English, but I can't find a better word. What I mean is "happy and sad at the same time". In my native language it is "đặc biệt" and I [translated it to "special"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=vi&tl=en&text=%C4%91%E1%BA%B7c%20bi%E1%BB%87t). Feel free to edit it!

Comment: @Baldrickk C (tcc) on tio.run seems to work

Comment: You might want to update the heading apparently starting 4 months ago and ending on 14th march google staff computed 31,415,926,535,897 :-) digits of pi – crushing a 2016 record by trillions of digits. see https://www.npr.org/2019/03/14/703566696/the-woman-who-calculated-31-trillion-digits-of-pi

Comment: @NieDzejkob thanks!  but... `2.71828...` I think there is still a problem :D  at least it runs.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here's one with `\shapepar`, with great thanks to [flowframtk](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/index.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\newcommand{\sep}{\discretionary{}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\small%
\shapepar[1.00375pt]{{137.821777}%
{0.0}b{27.0}%
\\{0.0}t{27.0}{249.0}%
\\{11.955168}t{14.0}{250.0}%
\\{23.910336}t{2.0}{249.0}%
\\{27.074219}t{0.0}{135.5}st{135.5}{111.5}%
\\{35.865504}t{57.0}{35.0}t{179.0}{35.0}%
\\{47.820672}t{56.0}{34.0}t{178.0}{34.0}%
\\{59.775841}t{55.0}{34.0}t{177.0}{34.0}%
\\{71.731009}t{53.0}{35.0}t{175.0}{35.0}%
\\{83.686177}t{52.0}{34.0}t{174.0}{34.0}%
\\{95.641345}t{51.0}{34.0}t{173.0}{34.0}%
\\{107.596513}t{49.0}{35.0}t{171.0}{35.0}%
\\{119.551681}t{48.0}{34.0}t{170.0}{34.0}%
\\{131.506849}t{47.0}{34.0}t{169.0}{34.0}%
\\{135.137695}t{46.0}{35.0}t{168.0}{35.0}%
\\{143.462017}t{45.0}{35.0}t{168.0}{34.0}%
\\{154.276367}t{44.0}{34.0}t{166.0}{35.0}%
\\{155.417186}t{44.0}{34.0}t{166.0}{35.0}%
\\{163.378906}t{43.0}{34.0}t{166.0}{34.0}%
\\{167.372354}t{43.0}{34.0}t{165.0}{35.0}t{256.0}{3.0}%
\\{171.936859}t{42.0}{34.0}t{165.0}{35.0}t{253.0}{8.0}%
\\{179.327522}t{41.0}{35.0}t{165.0}{35.0}t{248.0}{13.0}%
\\{182.050781}t{41.0}{34.0}t{165.0}{36.0}t{245.0}{15.0}%
\\{187.185547}t{40.0}{35.0}t{166.0}{36.0}t{240.0}{17.0}%
\\{191.28269}t{40.0}{34.0}t{166.0}{39.0}t{235.0}{19.0}%
\\{193.214996}t{40.0}{34.0}t{166.0}{40.0}t{232.0}{20.0}%
\\{197.688477}t{39.0}{35.0}t{167.0}{50.0}jt{217.0}{31.0}%
\\{198.388672}t{39.0}{35.0}t{167.0}{80.0}%
\\{203.237858}t{39.0}{34.0}t{169.0}{72.0}%
\\{207.880219}t{38.0}{34.0}t{171.0}{64.0}%
\\{207.958008}t{38.0}{34.0}t{171.0}{64.0}%
\\{215.193026}t{37.0}{19.0}t{175.0}{49.0}%
\\{215.660156}t{37.0}{18.0}t{176.0}{47.0}%
\\{222.195312}t{37.0}{2.0}t{186.0}{23.0}%
\\{222.195312}e{37.0}%
\\{223.362305}t{191.0}{13.0}%
\\{223.362305}e{191.0}%
}%
3\sep{}.\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}5\sep{}8\sep{}9\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}6\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}9\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}7\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}8\sep{}9\sep{}9\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}0\sep{}3\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}4\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}0\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}5\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}2\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}0\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}5\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}2\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}8\sep{}3\sep{}1\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}3\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}7\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}2\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}8\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}3\sep{}1\sep{}5\sep{}5\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}5\sep{}4\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}8\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}0\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}0\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}1\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}7\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}1\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}8\sep{}5\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}0\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}9\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}3\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}8\sep{}8\sep{}5\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}2\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}8\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}1\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}9\sep{}8\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}3\sep{}3\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}4\sep{}4\sep{}0\sep{}6\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}0\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}3\sep{}9\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}2\sep{}4\sep{}7\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}9\sep{}0\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}9\sep{}8\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}3\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}7\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}3\sep{}9\sep{}2\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}6\sep{}2\sep{}9\sep{}3\sep{}1\sep{}7\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}3\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}4\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}8\sep{}4\sep{}6\sep{}7\sep{}6\sep{}6\sep{}9\sep{}4\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}1\sep{}3\sep{}2\sep{}0\sep{}0\sep{}0\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}8\sep{}1\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}1\sep{}4\sep{}5\sep{}2\sep{}6\sep{}3\sep{}5\sep{}6\sep{}0\sep{}8\sep{}2\sep{}7\sep{}7\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain, how to create the proper coordinates? It would be interesting to learn, how to do it for other symbols too.

Comment: @JonasStein I used flowframtk (linked above) ! Typed the π symbol via "Insert symbol" (https://bit.ly/2F5Rhahl); set the desired font size and family; convert to path; then export the `\shapepar` (https://bit.ly/2O4Lgib)

Comment: @JouleV That's what bounties are for. And you could save your upvote for later.

Comment: @LianTzeLim could you please use the real URL? The bitly link does not work.

Comment: The first link (How to Insert Symbol in flowframtk) is https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/newtext.shtml#fig:insertsymbol .
The second link (Exporting `\shapepar` from flowframtk) is https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/shapepar.shtml

Answer (score 53):

Some tessellated pi...

[image]

This one is done in plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), so compile with `mpost`.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
input colorbrewer-rgb;
beginfig(1);
    path pi; numeric t; t = 13;
    pi = (origin -- (5,0) -- (5,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,1) -- up -- cycle) scaled t;

    for i=1 upto 48:
        for j=1 upto 48:
            fill pi                              shifted (4t*i-2t*j, t*i+5t*j) withcolor Spectral[7][i mod 7 + 1];
            fill pi rotated 180 shifted (4t, 5t) shifted (4t*i-2t*j, t*i+5t*j) withcolor Spectral[7][(3+i) mod 7 + 1];
       endfor
    endfor
    clip currentpicture to unitsquare scaled 100t shifted (0, 32t);
endfig;
end.
```

You will need to load [Metapost Colorbrewer](https://ctan.org/pkg/metapost-colorbrewer?lang=en) for the colours...

Comment: Wonderful!!!! Very nice for my opinion.

Answer (score 48):

Writing π with the digits of π - using the `verbatim` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{0.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
     3.141592653589793238462643383279
   5028841971693993751058209749445923
  07816406286208998628034825342117067
  9821    48086         5132     
 823      06647        09384
46        09550        58223
17        25359        4081
          2848         1117
          4502         8410
          2701         9385
         21105        55964
         46229        48954
         9303         81964
         4288         10975
        66593         34461
       284756         48233
       78678          31652        71
      2019091         456485       66
     9234603           48610454326648
    2133936            0726024914127
    3724587             00660631558
    817488               152092096
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Based on ascii art drawing by Jorel - https://www.flickr.com/photos/jorel314/3352784321/

Comment: How did you format the code? By trial/error?

Answer (score 47):

For Pi day, the tikzlings decided to go on holidays. Unfortunately, the snowman could not come with them, so they sent him a postcard:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\newcommand{\palm}{%
    \foreach \x in {1.2,1.15,...,0} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.2*\x*(1-\x)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{0.3-0.11*\x};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angup}{-50-30*\x)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angdown}{20+30*\x)};
        \fill[bottom color=green!80!black,top color=green!0!brown,shift={(\x,\y)},rotate=\angup] (0,0) -- (0.05,0) -- (0.025+0.015*rnd,\len+0.03*rnd) -- cycle;
        \fill[top color=green!80!black,bottom color=green!0!brown,shift={(\x,\y)},rotate=\angdown] (0,0) -- (0.05,0) -- (0.025+0.015*rnd,-\len+0.03*rnd) -- cycle;
    }
}
\newcommand{\palmtree}{%
    \foreach \y in {0,0.05,...,2} {
        \fill[inner color=brown!40!yellow,outer color=brown] (0.1*\y*\y,\y) ellipse({0.2-0.015*\y} and 0.1);
    }
    \foreach \angle in {-20,-10,0} {
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0.3,2)},rotate=\angle]
            \palm
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,2)},rotate=-\angle,xscale=-1]
            \palm
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetseed{1}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.7,0)}]
        \palmtree
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.7,0)},xscale=-1]
        \palmtree
    \end{scope}
    \bear[hat,xshift=-1.6cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \coati[tophat,xshift=-1.2cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \koala[beret,xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \marmot[strawhat,xshift=-0.4cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \moles[harlequin,xshift=-0.0cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \mouse[strawhat=blue,xshift=0.4cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \owl[beret=green!50!black,xshift=0.8cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \penguin[tophat=red,xshift=1.2cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
    \sloth[hat=brown!40!yellow,xshift=1.6cm,yshift=1.9cm,scale=0.25];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 44):

We could extract the MetaPost paths for the glyph `\pi` from the font and draw it using LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
-- We need some utilities from ConTeXt
callbacks = callbacks or {}
callbacks.supported = callbacks.supported or {}
CONTEXTLMTXMODE = CONTEXTLMTXMODE or (status.obj_ptr == nil and 2 or 1)
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-fmt.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("node-ini.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("font-mps.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("font-shp.lua"))

-- That's a simple reimplemetation of ConTeXt's \showshape macro
function outlinepaths(character)
    local fontid      = font.current()
    local shapedata   = fonts.hashes.shapes[fontid] -- by index
    local chardata    = fonts.hashes.characters[fontid] -- by unicode
    local shapeglyphs = shapedata.glyphs or { }

    character = utf.byte(character)
    local c = chardata[character]
    if c then
        if not c.index then
            return {}
        end
        local glyph = shapeglyphs[c.index]
        if glyph and (glyph.segments or glyph.sequence) then
            local units  = shapedata.units or 1000
            local factor = 100/units
            local paths  = fonts.metapost.paths(glyph,factor)
            return paths
        end
    end
end
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}

\def\mpdefineoutlines#1{\directlua{
```

```lua
    local char = "\luaescapestring{#1}"
    local outlines = outlinepaths("#1")
    for i, path in ipairs(outlines) do
        tex.print("fill " .. path .. ";")
    end
```

```
  }}

\begin{document} 

\begin{mplibcode}

  \mpdefineoutlines{}

\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Instead of using `luamplib`, we could also simply `print` the path to the log file and copy it to a MetaPost file.  With some additonal formatting we get:

```
prologues := 3;
outputformat := "pdf";

beginfig(1)
  fill (56.70,40.70)
    .. controls (56.70,43.10) and (54.60,43.10)
    .. (52.70,43.10)
    -- (19.20,43.10)
    .. controls (17,43.10) and (13.20,43.10)
    .. (8.80,38.40)
    .. controls (5.30,34.50) and (2.70,29.90)
    .. (2.70,29.40)
    .. controls (2.70,29.40) and (2.70,28.40)
    .. (3.90,28.40)
    .. controls (4.70,28.40) and (4.90,28.80)
    .. (5.50,29.60)
    .. controls (10.40,37.30) and (16.20,37.30)
    .. (18.20,37.30)
    -- (23.90,37.30)
    .. controls (20.70,25.20) and (15.30,13.10)
    .. (11.10,4)
    .. controls (10.30,2.50) and (10.30,2.30)
    .. (10.30,1.60)
    .. controls (10.30,-0.30) and (11.90,-1.10)
    .. (13.20,-1.10)
    .. controls (16.20,-1.10) and (17,1.70)
    .. (18.20,5.40)
    .. controls (19.60,10) and (19.60,10.20)
    .. (20.90,15.20)
    -- (26.50,37.30)
    -- (37.80,37.30)
    .. controls (34.50,22.50) and (33.60,18.20)
    .. (33.60,11.50)
    .. controls (33.60,10) and (33.60,7.30)
    .. (34.40,3.90)
    .. controls (35.40,-0.50) and (36.50,-1.10)
    .. (38,-1.10)
    .. controls (40,-1.10) and (42.10,0.70)
    .. (42.10,2.70)
    .. controls (42.10,3.30) and (42.10,3.50)
    .. (41.50,4.90)
    .. controls (38.60,12.10) and (38.60,18.60)
    .. (38.60,21.40)
    .. controls (38.60,26.70) and (39.30,32.10)
    .. (40.40,37.30)
    -- (51.80,37.30)
    .. controls (53.10,37.30) and (56.70,37.30)
    .. (56.70,40.70)
    -- cycle;
endfig;
end
```

Or you can even use the path with TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \fill (56.70,40.70)
    .. controls (56.70,43.10) and (54.60,43.10)
    .. (52.70,43.10)
    -- (19.20,43.10)
    .. controls (17,43.10) and (13.20,43.10)
    .. (8.80,38.40)
    .. controls (5.30,34.50) and (2.70,29.90)
    .. (2.70,29.40)
    .. controls (2.70,29.40) and (2.70,28.40)
    .. (3.90,28.40)
    .. controls (4.70,28.40) and (4.90,28.80)
    .. (5.50,29.60)
    .. controls (10.40,37.30) and (16.20,37.30)
    .. (18.20,37.30)
    -- (23.90,37.30)
    .. controls (20.70,25.20) and (15.30,13.10)
    .. (11.10,4)
    .. controls (10.30,2.50) and (10.30,2.30)
    .. (10.30,1.60)
    .. controls (10.30,-0.30) and (11.90,-1.10)
    .. (13.20,-1.10)
    .. controls (16.20,-1.10) and (17,1.70)
    .. (18.20,5.40)
    .. controls (19.60,10) and (19.60,10.20)
    .. (20.90,15.20)
    -- (26.50,37.30)
    -- (37.80,37.30)
    .. controls (34.50,22.50) and (33.60,18.20)
    .. (33.60,11.50)
    .. controls (33.60,10) and (33.60,7.30)
    .. (34.40,3.90)
    .. controls (35.40,-0.50) and (36.50,-1.10)
    .. (38,-1.10)
    .. controls (40,-1.10) and (42.10,0.70)
    .. (42.10,2.70)
    .. controls (42.10,3.30) and (42.10,3.50)
    .. (41.50,4.90)
    .. controls (38.60,12.10) and (38.60,18.60)
    .. (38.60,21.40)
    .. controls (38.60,26.70) and (39.30,32.10)
    .. (40.40,37.30)
    -- (51.80,37.30)
    .. controls (53.10,37.30) and (56.70,37.30)
    .. (56.70,40.70)
    -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is rather unspectacular.

[image]

Comment: I wonder (but don’t have anywhere near the TeX-fu to attack it myself): could one combine this answer with the [Liantze Lim’s shapepar-based answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479435/1635), to print the digits of pi (as there) in the shape of metafont’s actual pi (as used here), instead of with the shape input by hand (as it is there)?

Comment: You can sort of do it with ConTeXt to calculate `\parshape` but `\pi` is too irregular to give good results ([code](https://termbin.com/um2e), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Q4e.png)).

Answer (score 34):

Time for a bad joke...

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-3.000000, xscale=3.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[scale=0.265,fill=black,nonzero rule,line width=0.175pt]
    (391.8613,471.7441) .. controls (391.0467,471.6791) and (390.9815,472.0037) ..
    (392.4473,472.7852) .. controls (393.4234,473.3051) and (394.2051,473.8288) ..
    (394.2051,473.8926) .. controls (394.2051,474.1541) and (390.1011,473.8291) ..
    (387.6895,473.3730) .. controls (385.9318,473.0476) and (385.6071,473.1103) ..
    (386.3887,473.6973) .. controls (387.1702,474.2842) and (386.5841,474.3488) ..
    (383.9141,474.0234) .. controls (380.1372,473.5034) and (369.0009,474.3487) ..
    (371.0840,474.9355) .. controls (371.8017,475.1302) and (369.9119,475.4546) ..
    (366.8496,475.6523) .. controls (361.9658,475.9778) and (361.5745,476.1090) ..
    (363.5938,476.6289) -- (365.8750,477.2168) -- (363.9180,477.9980) .. controls
    (362.8749,478.4542) and (361.1186,478.9102) .. (360.0117,478.9102) --
    (358.0566,479.0410) -- (360.3340,479.8867) -- (362.6133,480.7324) --
    (359.0312,480.9922) .. controls (355.7105,481.2537) and (355.5810,481.3193) ..
    (357.5332,481.7754) .. controls (360.6593,482.5569) and (359.4882,483.4694) ..
    (355.2520,483.5332) .. controls (351.6696,483.5971) and (351.6064,483.5968) ..
    (353.6895,484.3145) -- (355.8379,484.9648) -- (353.3633,486.1387) .. controls
    (351.0825,487.2456) and (351.0829,487.3091) .. (352.8438,486.9199) .. controls
    (355.3829,486.4638) and (354.2754,487.7660) .. (351.6055,488.4199) .. controls
    (350.1062,488.7453) and (349.8471,488.6806) .. (350.2363,487.9629) .. controls
    (350.6255,487.2452) and (350.5622,487.1813) .. (349.8477,487.8320) .. controls
    (349.3915,488.2882) and (347.6333,488.6777) .. (345.9395,488.6777) .. controls
    (342.3571,488.6777) and (341.1837,489.6533) .. (344.1152,490.2402) .. controls
    (345.4837,490.5018) and (345.9412,490.8909) .. (345.5488,491.4141) .. controls
    (345.2872,491.8702) and (345.1589,492.7822) .. (345.2227,493.3691) .. controls
    (345.4172,494.4760) and (343.9842,494.5410) .. (322.7520,494.5410) .. controls
    (310.3112,494.6049) and (298.0685,494.8661) .. (295.5293,495.1914) .. controls
    (291.8162,495.6476) and (289.9274,495.5178) .. (285.1074,494.4746) .. controls
    (279.7005,493.2369) and (278.4641,493.2360) .. (268.5020,493.8867) .. controls
    (240.4975,495.7752) and (229.8169,500.0763) .. (221.2168,512.7754) .. controls
    (215.4845,521.1777) and (209.3638,540.1922) .. (207.6699,554.3906) .. controls
    (206.7576,562.1390) and (206.4307,563.4438) .. (204.3477,567.2207) .. controls
    (201.0907,573.0168) and (195.1644,579.2050) .. (190.2168,581.8750) .. controls
    (186.3825,583.9580) and (185.7311,584.0879) .. (180.1934,584.0879) .. controls
    (172.7034,584.0879) and (171.7914,583.4375) .. (171.1406,577.8359) .. controls
    (170.7483,574.5790) and (170.3591,573.7349) .. (168.4707,572.0410) .. controls
    (166.5153,570.3471) and (165.6705,570.0840) .. (162.6113,570.0840) --
    (158.9629,570.0840) -- (159.1562,572.9492) .. controls (159.2870,574.5123) and
    (159.2213,575.6861) .. (158.9629,575.4883) .. controls (158.6375,575.3575) and
    (158.4414,575.4885) .. (158.4414,575.8809) .. controls (158.4414,576.2063) and
    (158.7684,576.7260) .. (159.0938,576.9238) .. controls (159.4861,577.1854) and
    (159.6119,577.6414) .. (159.3535,577.9668) .. controls (159.1590,578.3560) and
    (159.6156,579.3995) .. (160.4609,580.2481) .. controls (161.8294,581.7473) and
    (161.8934,581.8104) .. (160.7227,581.4180) .. controls (158.8342,580.7672) and
    (165.4767,586.7580) .. (168.5391,588.5156) .. controls (170.7529,589.7533) and
    (172.1209,589.9492) .. (177.3301,589.9492) .. controls (183.5824,589.8853) and
    (189.1832,588.9048) .. (192.5039,587.2109) .. controls (194.2616,586.2986) and
    (194.3285,586.3658) .. (193.6777,587.6035) .. controls (193.2854,588.3212) and
    (191.3982,590.2097) .. (189.5098,591.9004) -- (186.0566,594.8320) --
    (185.3398,603.8184) .. controls (184.8837,608.7021) and (184.7534,613.5219) ..
    (184.9512,614.4981) .. controls (185.1457,615.4742) and (184.6892,617.7561) ..
    (183.9746,619.7754) .. controls (182.7369,623.0323) and (182.6727,624.1382) ..
    (183.1289,631.4336) .. controls (183.2964,634.1191) and (183.4845,636.1229) ..
    (183.7188,637.6973) -- (170.7891,636.3867) -- (172.2559,647.7539) .. controls
    (175.2172,670.7066) and (187.6454,715.3502) .. (195.3809,730.8203) .. controls
    (202.2667,744.5919) and (204.4715,747.0422) .. (214.9453,752.5703) --
    (226.7500,758.8008) -- (383.2656,758.1445) -- (539.7812,757.4902) --
    (552.2402,751.3848) .. controls (575.3569,740.0606) and (587.7187,721.6392) ..
    (601.6914,677.7012) .. controls (606.4682,662.6826) and (611.0325,642.4057) ..
    (612.6113,630.8711) .. controls (620.8351,626.0502) and (626.1090,616.1553) ..
    (627.6914,610.5098) -- (623.9062,609.4492) .. controls (621.5253,616.5571) and
    (616.6045,620.7654) .. (609.1269,619.0098) .. controls (588.9114,613.6352) and
    (609.9961,581.0584) .. (618.5039,551.2246) -- (642.3906,558.0644) --
    (646.5371,542.7539) .. controls (547.2330,514.4010) and (560.4002,515.9883) ..
    (538.3301,543.9141) -- (541.9043,545.2070) .. controls (546.8886,541.9876) and
    (551.9234,529.7436) .. (573.5312,538.4727) .. controls (557.5158,592.4920) and
    (532.1226,591.5464) .. (530.4902,603.0918) .. controls (529.2630,609.5511) and
    (533.1780,614.8277) .. (538.5215,616.5684) .. controls (555.7617,620.7688) and
    (561.4494,597.5315) .. (583.0312,540.9902) -- (605.0625,547.1660) .. controls
    (598.1578,567.2929) and (589.2261,586.8502) .. (583.2461,606.7988) .. controls
    (581.5364,613.4114) and (582.1595,619.0459) .. (584.5039,623.4297) .. controls
    (579.0468,623.8935) and (573.0937,624.4395) .. (566.8867,625.0527) .. controls
    (518.1395,629.8680) and (404.6183,638.3535) .. (388.9492,638.3535) .. controls
    (384.6987,638.5117) and (380.5242,638.6445) .. (376.3848,638.7656) .. controls
    (376.2582,638.0879) and (375.9270,637.3749) .. (375.3828,636.6367) .. controls
    (373.1020,633.4468) and (372.1276,632.9238) .. (367.8945,632.9238) --
    (363.9219,632.9238) -- (362.1641,629.6660) .. controls (360.5372,626.7345) and
    (360.3398,625.7597) .. (360.3398,620.1582) .. controls (360.3398,613.6443) and
    (361.4471,608.1735) .. (365.1602,596.3867) .. controls (366.7870,591.3083) and
    (369.3284,587.6584) .. (369.9121,589.4160) .. controls (370.1067,589.9360) and
    (371.4123,590.2617) .. (373.3008,590.2617) .. controls (375.8400,590.2617) and
    (377.7955,590.9789) .. (384.5039,594.6250) .. controls (399.2893,602.5042) and
    (403.6531,605.3713) .. (403.8477,607.2598) .. controls (404.1092,609.2152) and
    (405.2163,610.3868) .. (409.7109,613.3184) .. controls (411.9917,614.8177) and
    (413.2924,616.3145) .. (414.7246,619.2461) .. controls (416.4823,622.7646) and
    (417.0061,623.2839) .. (420.2598,624.6523) .. controls (423.3221,625.8901) and
    (424.5573,626.0851) .. (428.7266,625.7598) .. controls (431.3965,625.4982) and
    (434.1324,625.1718) .. (434.7832,625.0410) .. controls (436.1517,624.6487) and
    (438.1708,620.8090) .. (438.7578,617.4883) .. controls (439.2778,614.4929) and
    (438.8219,614.0364) .. (429.4434,608.3711) .. controls (423.9726,605.0504) and
    (421.8227,603.2925) .. (418.5020,599.3848) .. controls (411.9243,591.7002) and
    (411.9235,591.6354) .. (402.8066,583.4277) .. controls (398.1174,579.1309) and
    (394.2109,575.4817) .. (394.2109,575.2871) .. controls (394.2109,575.0925) and
    (395.7091,572.6185) .. (397.4668,569.7539) .. controls (399.6168,566.3662) and
    (400.9859,563.3054) .. (401.5059,560.8301) .. controls (402.3512,556.7278) and
    (403.0043,556.1424) .. (403.9805,558.6816) .. controls (404.8928,561.0900) and
    (405.6756,560.6367) .. (405.4141,557.8359) -- (405.2188,555.4277) --
    (406.5195,557.0547) .. controls (407.2373,557.9670) and (407.8887,559.3982) ..
    (407.8887,560.3106) .. controls (407.8887,561.6121) and (408.0191,561.7425) ..
    (408.5391,560.9609) .. controls (408.8645,560.4410) and (408.9954,559.3994) ..
    (408.8008,558.6816) .. controls (408.4084,557.4439) and (408.4082,557.4434) ..
    (409.7129,558.7481) .. controls (410.4306,559.5296) and (411.1452,560.8312) ..
    (411.3398,561.6797) .. controls (411.5345,562.9174) and (411.6655,562.7219) ..
    (411.7324,561.0918) .. controls (411.7963,558.6164) and (412.9699,558.5539) ..
    (414.1406,560.8984) -- (414.9219,562.3965) -- (415.3789,561.0293) .. controls
    (415.8989,559.3355) and (417.0053,559.8551) .. (417.0723,561.8106) .. controls
    (417.1392,563.1120) and (417.2040,563.1114) .. (417.6602,561.6152) --
    (418.1797,559.9883) -- (418.3105,561.6152) .. controls (418.4413,563.2421) and
    (418.4418,563.2433) .. (419.2871,561.2910) .. controls (419.8071,560.1841) and
    (420.1979,559.7913) .. (420.2617,560.3144) .. controls (420.2617,561.0322) and
    (420.6522,560.8335) .. (421.5645,559.7266) -- (422.8652,558.2285) --
    (422.8652,560.1191) .. controls (422.8652,561.1622) and (422.3447,562.6593) ..
    (421.7578,563.5078) .. controls (421.1708,564.4201) and (421.0418,564.8748) ..
    (421.4980,564.6133) .. controls (421.9542,564.2879) and (422.8656,563.1817) ..
    (423.5801,562.0078) .. controls (424.9486,559.7940) and (425.2749,560.9649) ..
    (424.1680,563.8965) .. controls (423.7788,564.8726) and (423.7782,565.4588) ..
    (424.1035,565.1973) .. controls (424.4289,565.0026) and (425.0790,563.7650) ..
    (425.5352,562.3965) .. controls (426.3167,559.9211) and (428.5978,556.6004) ..
    (429.1816,556.9258) .. controls (429.3763,557.0566) and (429.7684,556.7960) ..
    (430.0938,556.3398) .. controls (431.1369,554.6460) and (431.3316,556.2750) ..
    (430.3555,558.5527) .. controls (428.8562,562.0712) and (429.8985,561.4840) ..
    (431.5254,557.8379) .. controls (432.3707,555.8824) and (432.9578,555.1683) ..
    (433.1523,555.8828) .. controls (433.2831,556.4698) and (433.0226,557.5765) ..
    (432.6973,558.2910) .. controls (431.8519,559.8541) and (431.7848,560.8297) ..
    (432.5664,559.9844) .. controls (432.8918,559.5952) and (433.4794,558.1608) ..
    (433.9355,556.7285) .. controls (434.6533,554.5785) and (434.8471,554.3208) ..
    (435.2363,555.4277) .. controls (435.6925,556.5346) and (435.8238,556.4021) ..
    (436.3438,554.5137) .. controls (437.2561,551.1259) and (438.4922,551.1935) ..
    (438.4922,554.5781) -- (438.5566,557.3789) -- (439.7305,554.4531) .. controls
    (440.3812,552.8263) and (441.4255,550.6134) .. (442.0762,549.5703) --
    (443.1816,547.6152) -- (442.8574,550.5469) .. controls (442.5320,553.2169) and
    (442.5949,553.3477) .. (443.4434,552.1738) .. controls (443.9633,551.4561) and
    (444.7463,549.6979) .. (445.1387,548.2656) .. controls (445.7894,545.8572) and
    (445.9188,545.7898) .. (446.2441,547.2891) .. controls (446.7003,548.8522) and
    (446.7015,548.8526) .. (447.5469,546.7695) .. controls (448.4592,544.5557) and
    (449.2398,544.1641) .. (449.7598,545.4688) .. controls (449.9544,545.9249) and
    (450.1523,545.7288) .. (450.1523,544.9473) .. controls (450.2162,543.7096) and
    (450.7384,543.5148) .. (455.1660,543.1894) .. controls (459.8552,542.8640) and
    (460.3117,542.6695) .. (462.6562,540.3887) .. controls (464.0247,539.0872) and
    (465.4579,537.0698) .. (465.9141,535.9629) .. controls (466.3702,534.8560) and
    (467.6718,533.0301) .. (468.8457,531.8594) .. controls (470.0834,530.6887) and
    (471.0586,529.1904) .. (471.0586,528.4727) .. controls (471.0586,527.7549) and
    (469.0392,524.9532) .. (466.5000,522.2832) .. controls (463.7630,519.2879) and
    (461.9434,516.8127) .. (461.9434,515.9004) .. controls (461.9434,515.1188) and
    (461.3552,513.8811) .. (460.6406,513.0996) .. controls (459.9261,512.3181) and
    (458.6227,509.9103) .. (457.7773,507.6934) .. controls (456.8650,505.4795) and
    (455.3017,502.4160) .. (454.2617,500.7891) .. controls (453.2186,499.2260) and
    (451.9796,496.8816) .. (451.5234,495.5801) .. controls (451.1343,494.3424) and
    (450.4816,493.1048) .. (450.1562,492.9102) .. controls (449.8308,492.6486) and
    (449.5684,491.3483) .. (449.5684,489.9160) .. controls (449.5684,486.9207) and
    (447.6793,483.5986) .. (444.0332,480.2109) .. controls (441.9502,478.3225) and
    (441.6264,478.1920) .. (442.0156,479.4297) .. controls (442.7334,481.5127) and
    (441.7525,481.1881) .. (438.5625,478.2598) .. controls (435.3726,475.2644) and
    (432.0492,473.4398) .. (428.7285,472.7891) -- (426.4473,472.3965) --
    (429.5098,474.2852) .. controls (433.7428,477.0221) and (434.0691,477.9983) ..
    (429.9668,475.9121) -- (426.4473,474.2168) -- (428.0742,475.9746) --
    (429.7012,477.8008) -- (427.0957,476.1055) .. controls (425.6634,475.1294) and
    (423.8395,474.3477) .. (422.9941,474.3477) .. controls (422.2126,474.3477) and
    (421.3657,473.8930) .. (421.1680,473.3730) .. controls (420.9064,472.8531) and
    (420.1917,472.3965) .. (419.4102,472.3965) .. controls (418.1724,472.3965) and
    (418.1085,472.4627) .. (419.2793,473.6973) .. controls (420.6478,475.2603) and
    (420.4505,475.2598) .. (417.5859,474.0859) .. controls (416.3482,473.6298) and
    (413.9400,473.0442) .. (412.2461,472.8496) -- (409.0566,472.5234) --
    (411.2695,474.4121) .. controls (413.8087,476.6259) and (413.5516,476.6926) ..
    (409.7715,475.0625) .. controls (406.9069,473.8248) and (400.2625,473.1071) ..
    (398.9609,473.8887) .. controls (398.6355,474.0833) and (397.2018,473.6936) ..
    (395.7695,473.0430) .. controls (394.2384,472.2630) and (392.6760,471.8091) ..
    (391.8613,471.7441) -- cycle(276.5215,566.2402) -- (279.3223,568.1973) ..
    controls (283.8807,571.3234) and (291.3057,574.5792) .. (296.1895,575.6191) ..
    controls (308.9556,578.2891) and (318.9856,577.3135) .. (328.5586,572.4297) ..
    controls (333.3786,569.9543) and (335.0047,569.4336) .. (338.0000,569.4336) ..
    controls (340.6062,569.4336) and (342.0383,569.7603) .. (343.2090,570.7363) ..
    controls (344.1213,571.4541) and (345.2300,572.0371) .. (345.6191,572.0371) ..
    controls (346.0083,572.0371) and (346.9867,572.5563) .. (347.8320,573.2070) ..
    controls (349.2643,574.3139) and (349.2652,574.4462) .. (348.2891,576.3984) ..
    controls (347.4437,578.0923) and (347.3126,581.0873) .. (347.4434,595.2188) ..
    controls (347.6379,611.4364) and (347.5729,612.2178) .. (346.1406,615.9277) --
    (344.6426,619.7676) -- (346.0098,621.2012) .. controls (346.9859,622.2443) and
    (347.3125,623.4809) .. (347.3125,625.9531) .. controls (347.3125,628.2339) and
    (347.8319,630.3806) .. (348.8750,632.4668) .. controls (349.7203,634.1606) and
    (350.7639,636.5703) .. (351.1562,637.8750) .. controls (351.3326,638.4122) and
    (351.5011,638.8830) .. (351.6797,639.3027) .. controls (335.5248,639.5443) and
    (320.0184,639.5715) .. (304.7266,639.5254) .. controls (305.7587,639.3505) and
    (306.2745,639.0478) .. (306.8691,638.5352) .. controls (307.7145,637.7536) and
    (308.9521,637.1660) .. (309.5391,637.1660) .. controls (310.1260,637.1660) and
    (310.7775,636.9719) .. (311.0391,636.7773) .. controls (311.6898,636.1266) and
    (308.3685,630.1331) .. (307.0000,629.3516) .. controls (305.0446,628.3755) and
    (301.5932,628.5691) .. (296.1895,630.0684) .. controls (290.1988,631.6953) and
    (290.9143,632.0231) .. (281.7305,623.0977) .. controls (275.4782,616.9762) and
    (275.1520,616.4541) .. (274.3066,612.7441) .. controls (273.1997,607.4042) and
    (273.2643,604.0163) .. (274.6328,597.1133) .. controls (275.4144,593.2726) and
    (275.9331,586.9538) .. (276.1309,578.7461) -- (276.5215,566.2402) --
    cycle(243.8203,570.0820) .. controls (244.0149,570.0820) and
    (245.6453,573.7951) .. (247.3359,578.3535) .. controls (249.0298,582.9789) and
    (251.9611,589.6208) .. (253.7188,593.2031) -- (256.9785,599.7188) --
    (256.8477,608.9023) .. controls (256.7839,614.1115) and (256.9794,619.2572) ..
    (257.4355,620.8203) .. controls (258.0225,623.1649) and (258.6725,623.7517) ..
    (262.8418,626.1602) .. controls (265.4480,627.6594) and (271.5023,631.2384) ..
    (276.3223,634.1699) -- (285.1152,639.4473) .. controls (255.9661,639.4473) and
    (227.5437,639.1752) .. (208.3731,638.7637) .. controls (208.1397,637.8716) and
    (207.5751,636.8804) .. (206.6387,635.7305) .. controls (204.8140,633.5167) and
    (204.2940,633.3228) .. (200.9062,633.1250) -- (197.1934,632.9297) --
    (197.2578,624.7891) .. controls (197.2578,617.2353) and (197.4514,616.2568) ..
    (199.3398,611.3731) .. controls (202.1406,604.2754) and (204.8119,600.4308) ..
    (209.1758,597.3047) .. controls (211.1950,595.8054) and (215.6221,592.2265) ..
    (219.0098,589.2949) .. controls (222.3975,586.3634) and (227.6701,582.1298) ..
    (230.7324,579.9160) .. controls (233.7948,577.7022) and (237.8974,574.5767) ..
    (239.8496,573.0137) .. controls (241.8050,571.3868) and (243.6257,570.0820) ..
    (243.8203,570.0820) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Life of Pi]

For a tiger, there's a lot of code, [so it's available here](https://gist.github.com/cereda/bee462efd395ae0bf632ed7b3b780234). The output:

[image: Life of Pi]

Comment: I like the idea. Never heard of the book or the movie. I know the book with the tiger but the image shows (as far as I can see) a lion.

Comment: ooh you switched the tiger to Lions of TikZ :-) that really is a fun answer I'm sorry I put your name to my poor version

Comment: I demand a tiger… Thanks for a good laugh ;-) @albert The movie was awesome, another masterpiece by Ang Lee.

Comment: @albert, @ RuixiZhang, @KJO, @samcarter: updated. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Long live the Inkscape!

Comment: I didn't follow the joke :-(

Comment: @Sigur oh no worries, it's from a movie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi_(film) `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, oh, now makes sense.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a slightly different visualization of π.

[image]

I re-drew this from my copy of [*Proofs without Words*](http://www.librarything.com/work/7711397) by Roger B. Nelsen.  The original was published in *Mathematics Magazine*, 50.3, May 1977.

Here I have used [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(0);
    path C, C', S; numeric u; u=68;
    C = fullcircle rotated 90 scaled 2u;
    C' = C rotated 180 shifted (3.14159265359u ,0); 
    S = unitsquare rotated -90 
                   scaled 1.77245385091u
                   shifted point 0 of C'; 

    z0 = (xpart point 2 of C', ypart point 0 of C');
    fill C withcolor 7/8[blue,white]; 
    fill S withcolor 7/8[blue,white]; 

    drawoptions(dashed withdots scaled 1/2);
    draw point 4 of C shifted (-u,0) -- point 3 of S shifted (1/2u,0);
    draw halfcircle rotated 180 
                    scaled abs(point 4 of C - z0)
                    shifted 1/2[point 4 of C,z0];
    drawoptions();
    forsuffixes @=C,C':
        draw @; 
        draw point 0 of @ -- center @ -- point 2 of @ dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
        drawdot point 0 of @ withpen pencircle scaled 3;
    endfor 
    draw point 2 of C' -- z0 dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
    draw S;
    drawarrow subpath(-1/2,-3/2) of C scaled 1.2 withcolor 2/3 red;

    label.top("The Rolling Circle Squares Itself — Thomas Elsner", 
                    1/2[point 0 of C, point 4 of C'] shifted 20 up);
    label.bot("$\pi$", 1/2[point 4 of C, point 0 of C']);
    label.lft("$\sqrt\pi$", 1/2[point 1 of S, point 0 of C']);
    label.rt("$1$", 1/2 point 0 of C);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I like that you showed what Pi *is* rather than the symbol. (You've also inspired me to learn luamplib.)

Answer (score 30):

[image]

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usepackage{pst-text,pst-eucl,pst-grad}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\DeclareFixedFont{\ps}{U}{psy}{m}{n}{12cm}% the symbol font
\DeclareFixedFont{\PS}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{11cm}% the times font
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}

\def\x{3.43}

\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    linestyle=none,
    fillstyle=gradient,
    gradlines=1500,
    gradangle=30,
    gradmidpoint=1,
}

\newrgbcolor{TopBegin}{0.027 0.6 0.254}
\newrgbcolor{TopEnd}{0.521 0.749 0.125}

\newrgbcolor{LeftBegin}{0 0.368 0.549}
\newrgbcolor{LeftEnd}{0 0.596 0.701}

\newrgbcolor{BottomBegin}{0.905 0.223 0.050}
\newrgbcolor{BottomEnd}{0.949 0.568 0.003}

\newrgbcolor{RightBegin}{0.513 0.117 0.380}
\newrgbcolor{RightEnd}{0.870 0.007 0.349}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\x,\x)(\x,-\x)
    \pstGeonode(-\x,\x){TL}(-\x,-\x){BL}(\x,-\x){BR}(\x,\x){TR}
    \pstGeonode
        (-2.4,1.7){A}
        (-1.2,1.7){B}
        (-1.5,-2.2){C}
        (0.7,-2.3){D}
        (1.0,1.7){E}
    \only<6>{\psclip{\pscircle[linewidth=0,fillstyle=none]{\x}}}
        \only<1->{\pspolygon[gradbegin=TopBegin,gradend=TopEnd](TL)(A)(E)(TR)}
        \only<2->{\pspolygon[gradbegin=LeftBegin,gradend=LeftEnd](TL)(A)(B)(C)(BL)}
        \only<3->{\pspolygon[gradbegin=BottomBegin,gradend=BottomEnd](BL)(C)(B)(E)(D)(BR)}
        \only<4->{\pspolygon[gradbegin=RightBegin,gradend=RightEnd](BR)(D)(E)(TR)}
        \only<5->{\rput(-0.2,-0.45){\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]{\ps p}}}
    \only<6>{\endpsclip}
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unnecessary edit: Today is a pi's day!

Answer (score 24):

My contribuation for pi(e)-day:

[image]

The thieves were already there:

[image]

Comment: Did you use LaTeX to prepare the cake? :-)

Comment: @gerrit a bit - it was used to get a prototype for the pi and the ducks ;-)

Comment: You staged it, right? There is no way the Baer is faster at the cake than the marmot.

Comment: @marmot The marmot is rather cautious and sent the Bär to check the situation.

Answer (score 21):

The obligatory `forest` solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\forestset{
  forked edge'/.style={
    edge={rotate/.option=!parent.grow},
    edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)++(0pt,-30pt) -- (!u.parent anchor)++(0pt,30pt)  |- (.child anchor)},   
  }
}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{forest}forked edges,for tree={edge={line width=4pt}}
[ [ ] [ ]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: pi]

Comment: Hah! I can't see the forest from the `\pi`'s

Answer (score 20):

One should also honor Euler a bit.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings,amsmath}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{/thing/.cd,
 pie/.code=\thing@cheesetrue\def\thing@cheese{#1}, %<-pretend you didn't see that
 pie/.default=pink!70!red}
\makeatother                            
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\marmot[pie,whiskers,teeth,shadow]
\node[anchor=east,scale=5,transform shape] at (-0.6,1) {$\pi\cdot\mathsf{e}=\text{\sffamily pie}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do marmots even eat pink cheese? Hahah. All the answers including the question are fantastic.

Answer (score 20):

A few mathematical representations:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
    \[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Honory representation: Ramanujan's equation**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[\sqrt{6}\cdot\prod_{p~\text{prime}}^{\infty}\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In a computer programmer's paradigm:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[4\cdot\arctan{1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the computer programmer's method for obtaining it as a double precision constant:  pi = 4 atan(1).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Another possibility :D

Comment: @Raaja Your answer, with [Reda Drissi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479478/156344), [seem to be off-topic in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479395/welcoming-2019-pi-day-how-to-draw-the-letter-%CF%80#comment1211340_479478) :) (but don't worry, I like them all!)

Comment: @JouleV I know, therefore, I posted this answer as a community wiki `;)`. IMO, these are some of the must-to-be-added answers for the sake of `\pi` day `;)`, because, their scope is beyond `TeX` by itself. Nevertheless, thank you for liking the answer(s). And, I still owe you a `pie` from `TikZ` which, I am baking now.

Comment: @Raaja You made me hungry, and your comment makes me starving :))

Answer (score 20):

In honor of Archimedes....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
\foreach \x/\y in {6/Pink,12/Yellow,24/LightGreen,48/Orange,96/Magenta}
 {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[White] (0,0) circle(3.2cm);
\draw[fill=\y] (0,0) circle(3cm);
\foreach \z in {1,...,\x}
 {
  \pgfmathsetmacro\rx{3*cos(360*(\z/\x))};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ry{3*sin(360*(\z/\x))};
  \draw (0,0)--(\rx,\ry);
  \pgfmathsetmacro\rxp{3*cos(360*((\z-1)/\x))};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ryp{3*sin(360*((\z-1)/\x))};
  \draw (\rxp,\ryp)--(\rx,\ry);
};
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
\raisebox{3cm}{Archimedes's algorithm for computing $\pi$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

This `lua` code shows how to use Monte Carlo simulation (MCS) to estimate π. Approach and Matlab solution is [here](http://web.mst.edu/~dux/repository/multimedia/problem_1/Problem_statement_MCS_PI.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tp=tex.print
N=5000000 --[[ the experiment event number ]]
r=1 --[[ the circle radius ]]
n=0 --[[ sucessful event number  ]]
for i = 1,N,1 
do 
   x=-r+2*r*math.random()
   y=-r+2*r*math.random()
   if ((x*x+y*y)<=r*r) then n = n+1  end
end
lua_pi = 4*n/N
tp("Estimated value of pi :")  tp(lua_pi)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I scrolled all the way down here to find a solution that uses the computational powers of tex to actually estimate pi, great!

Answer (score 17):

```
\def\Tau{\ooalign{%
  $\bigcirc$\cr
  \hskip.3em $^\circ$\cr
  \hskip.49em \vrule depth .5ex height .95ex width .4pt
}}
$$ \Tau\over 2 $$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Finally a relief from all those half-turn heretics!

Comment: +1. We should make June 28 a thing, too.

Comment: ok so this is a reference to tau, but what's the robot got to do with it?

Comment: @LarsH it‘s a [Tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%27au_Empire) unit miniature from the tabletop game Warhammer 40k.

Answer (score 15):

My little litle litle...........contribution...with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}       
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw[line width=2mm, violet] (221,106) .. controls (261,76) and (315.5,126) .. (355.5,96) ;
\draw[line width=1.5mm, violet] (254.5,98) -- (239.5,176) ;
\draw[line width=1.5mm, violet] (318,107) -- (335.5,179) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or.....this

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    \draw[line width=3mm, orange] (200,103) .. controls (240,73) and (267.5,123) .. (307.5,93) ;
    \draw[line width=2.3mm, orange] (226.5,160) .. controls (244.5,158) and (235.5,136) .. (235.5,94) ;
    \draw[line width=2.3mm, orange]  (284.5,160) .. controls (276.5,152) and (276.5,140.75) .. (276.13,134.75) .. controls (275.75,128.75) and (276,122) .. (274.5,103) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

.....and for my students `:-)` this: ℒ(C)/(2r) = π

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (125,142.25) .. controls (125,90.2) and (167.2,48) .. (219.25,48) .. controls (271.3,48) and (313.5,90.2) .. (313.5,142.25) .. controls (313.5,194.3) and (271.3,236.5) .. (219.25,236.5) .. controls (167.2,236.5) and (125,194.3) .. (125,142.25) -- cycle ;
\draw[|-|,red]   (219.25,142.25) -- (287.54,207.96) ;
\draw (248,184) node   {$r$};
\draw (325,92) node   {$\ell(\mathcal{C})$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

Do you know what the value of *π* is? Here is an answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newlength{\numheight}
\settoheight{\numheight}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={\numheight/2},y={\numheight/2}]
\draw (-6,-.2)|-(-5,0) (-5.6,0)--(-5.75,-1) (-5.3,0)--(-5.3,-.875) arc (180:360:.125);
\draw (-4.5,.25) to[out=60,in=-120] (-3.5,.25) (-4.5,-.25) to[out=60,in=-120] (-3.5,-.25);
\draw (-3,0) arc (-90:90:1 and 0.5) (-3,0) arc (90:-90:1 and 0.5);
\draw (-1,-1) circle (.1pt);
\draw (.5,-1)|-(0,1) (0,-1)--(1,-1);
\draw (2,1)--(1.5,0)--(2.5,0) (2.5,1)--(2.5,-1);
\draw (3.5,-1)|-(3,1) (3,-1)--(4,-1);
\draw (5.5,1)-|(4.5,0) arc (90:-90:1 and 0.5);
\draw (6.5,0)-|(7,.5) arc (0:270:0.5) (7,0) arc (0:-90:1);
\draw (7.5,.5) arc (180:-60:0.5) to[out=210,in=90] (7.5,-1)--(8.5,-1);
\draw (9,-.5)|-(9.5,0) arc (90:-180:0.5) (9,0) arc (180:90:1);
\draw (11.5,1)-|(10.5,0) arc (90:-90:1 and 0.5);
\draw (12,0) arc (-90:90:1 and 0.5) (12,0) arc (90:-90:1 and 0.5);
\draw (13.5,-.5)|-(14,0) arc (90:-180:0.5) (13.5,0) arc (180:90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't worry about the spacing. This is supposed to be in a monospaced font :))

Without code...

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A bit rough, but anyway.

[image: pi image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-\Gin@driver}
\usepackage{pgfsys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
 /pgf/fpu=true,
 /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
}
\def\pgfpt{\dimexpr\pgfmathresult pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\Large
\hspace{5mm}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,90}{%
 \pgfmathparse{-sin(\i) * 50}%
 \raisebox{\pgfpt}{.}%
 \pgfmathparse{(cos(\i) - cos(\i - 1)) * 5 - 4}%
 \hspace{\pgfpt}%
}\\
\hspace{-2mm}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,50}{.\hspace{-3pt}}\\
\hspace{-8mm}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,120}{%
 \pgfmathparse{-sin(\i) * 50}%
 \raisebox{\pgfpt}{.}%
 \pgfmathparse{(cos(\i) - cos(\i - 1)) * 5 - 3.7}%
 \hspace{\pgfpt}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

Happy `\pi`(less) day!!

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\rule{30pt}{1pt}\\[-1pt]
\rule{8pt}{0pt}%
\rule{1pt}{30pt}%
\rule{12pt}{0pt}%
\rule{1pt}{30pt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use different representations like :

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
    \[\sqrt{6\sum\limits^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}\]
 \end{document}
```

[image: latex.codecogs representation]

Or the gamma function :

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
    \[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use Leibniz Wallis or BBP formula.

Comment: while this is true, I think, the answer misses the purpose of the topic...

Comment: @naphaneal, Yea, but it's a Pi Day post, so have an upvote.  You too.

Answer (score 10):

My small contribution with some **slagroom vlaai** `;-)` (I really think, we should not omit this one).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
How can we forget this: $\pi$.

Anyway a happy pie day:

\includegraphics[height=2in, width=2in]{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After baking the `PIE` for `JouleV` in `tikz`:

```
%&lualatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]


\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
% % lets bake some pi with a nice recipe from: https://helloacm.com/r-programming-tutorial-how-to-compute-pi-using-monte-carlo-in-r/

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]

\foreach \i in {1,...,10000}{
    % Lets start baking the PI(E)
\pgfmathparse{rnd}
%VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{rnd}
%VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\x*\x+\y*\y)}
%VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\t^0.5)}
%VARIABLES
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\pgfmathresult}

% now the comparison
\pgfmathparse{notgreater(\z,1)} 
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 
\addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(\x,\y)};
\else
\addplot[yellow, mark=*] coordinates {(\x,\y)};
\fi

}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: I don't think `\includegraphics` qualifies as drawing.

Comment: @Henri Menke too bad that you didn't like/want the vlaai ;)

Comment: @Raaja We all want it :)) but I think Henri Menke wants a Ti*k*Zified version :v

Comment: @JouleV I will try to bake one this weekend ;)

Comment: @Raaja Hope I can eat it soon :D

Comment: +1 for vlaai :D

Comment: @Marijn Thank you ;)

Comment: Are we nearly there yet? is it only half baked?

Comment: @KJO My oven (PC) is a little bit rusty `;-)`. I am still waiting for it myself :D (been more than 20 mins).

Comment: @HenriMenke I finally baked a `\pi` with `Tikz`. Atleast now consider tasting the vlaai :D

Comment: OMG my oven just blew up (capacity exceeded) theres doh! all over my face because I did not see that coming. I will try half a pie first

Comment: @KJO That is why I specifically mentioned that you must use your oven in `Lualatex` mode :D

Comment: I used \for each \i in {1,...,750}{% Lets start baking the PI(E) then the mice stole the other threequarters, and who reads the manual anyway doh!

Comment: @KJO But you wont experience the full pie though :D. Now you can enjoy it via my complete answer :D

Comment: Looks like the mice have nibbled yours at the edges too

Comment: @KJO ofcourse, it's due to the approximation ;) if you have infinite memory capacity, you can use infinite set of random numbers to perfectly approximate the pie.

Comment: would it not be easier to just do what google did and compute pi to 3.14... trillion  places ? only took them 4 months [edit] I'm trying another tin in the lua assisted oven but its taking foreeeeeeeeeeeever

Comment: @KJO it will kill the fun. Ofcpurse in my rusty PC it look almost an hour :D

Answer (score 6):

Run both with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-text} 
\newcommand*\PI{%
3{,}%
1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679%
8214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196%
4428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273%
7245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094%
3305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912%
9833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132%
0005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235%
4201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859%
5024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303%
5982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989%
3809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151%
5574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012%
8583616035637076601047101819429555961989467678374494482553797747268471040475346462080466842590694912%
9331367702898915210475216205696602405803815019351125338243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279%
6782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955%
3211653449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746728909777727938000%
8164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115735255213347574184946843852332390739414333%
4547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383%
8279679766814541009538837863609506800642251252051173929848960841284886269456042419652850222106611863%
0674427862203919494504712371378696095636437191728746776465757396241389086583264599581339047802759009%
9465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203%
4962524517493996514314298091906592509372216964615157098583874105978859597729754989301617539284681382%
6868386894277415599185592524595395943104997252468084598727364469584865383673622262609912460805124388%
4390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506%
0168427394522674676788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743241125%
1507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330861792868092087476091782493858%
9009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364%
5428584447952658678210511413547357395231134271661021359695362314429524849371871101457654035902799344%
0374200731057853906219838744780847848968332144571386875194350643021845319104848100537061468067491927%
8191197939952061419663428754440643745123718192179998391015919561814675142691239748940907186494231961%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ps}{U}{psy}{m}{n}{12cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(15,5.5)
  \pstextpath{\pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
  \parametricplot[plotpoints=500]{0}{3510}{t cos t 600 div mul t sin t 600 div mul}
  \psline(!3510 cos 3510 600 div mul 30 add 3510 sin 3510 600 div mul)}}{\PI}
  \rput(0,-3.2){\pscharpath[linecolor=black!20,strokeopacity=0.8,
    fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40,opacity=0.75]{\rput[b](0,0){\ps p}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}      % PSTricks package for filling/tiling
\usepackage{pst-text}              % PSTricks package for character path
\begin{document}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ptsmall}{T1}{ptm}{m}{sc}{5mm}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ps}{U}{psy}{m}{n}{8cm}
\psboxfill{\ptsmall$\pi$}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,0)(2,4.5)
    \pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!20,addfillstyle=boxfill,
                fillangle=30,fillsep=0.6mm]%
                {\rput[b](-0.5,0){\ps\char112}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,math}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path,
text={3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233},
text effects/.cd,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={text along path, evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;},
text=orange!\c!blue, scale=\i/\n+0.5}}]
\draw[decorate , domain=-10:1080,variable=\t,samples=100]
      plot ({(\t+300)*cos(\t)/(720)},
           {(\t+300)*sin(\t)/(720)});

\node at (0,0){\Huge$\pi$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Wow...it is beautiful much much...my sincere compliments. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1pt,yunit=1pt,runit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(800,1200)
\pscustom[linewidth=15]{\newpath\moveto(170,992)\curveto(165,928)(152,855)(107,813)}
\pscustom[linewidth=15]{\newpath\moveto(253,973)\curveto(229,913)(250,823)(282,809)}
\pscustom[linewidth=15]{\newpath\moveto(88,962)\curveto(172,1053)(223,922)(327,996)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue] (-3.32,1.88) .. controls (-2.62,4.28) and (0.04,2.87) .. (1.48,3.41) .. controls (1.38,2.54) and (0.57,2.53) .. (0.09,2.48) .. controls (0.08,1.03) and (-0.48,-1.4) .. (0.82,-0.31) .. controls (0.78,-1.24) and (-1.71,-2.57) .. (-0.31,2.51) .. controls (-0.87,2.5) and (-0.87,2.5) .. (-1.48,2.53) .. controls (-1.49,1.31) and (-2.05,-1.77) .. (-2.93,-1.1) .. controls (-3.48,-0.36) and (-2.27,-0.74) .. (-1.88,2.55) .. controls (-2.47,2.51) and (-2.79,2.36) .. (-3.32,1.88);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]