# Reproducing the following "Pi" symbol in Latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

Can this PI symbol be exactly reproduced in Latex? I have tried various math packages like newtx, newpx,stix etc etc, but their PI shape doesn't match with the one i have in the image.

Thank you.

Comment: It is Symbol package .ttf font used in Word Office.

Comment: where did you get the image from, if it's a pdf or web page etc you should be able to access the font name. But why do you ask, it would be very odd to use a different font for just one symbol.

Comment: @crskhr the shape will depend on the font --- there are zillions of fonts out there, it will be very difficult to guess...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got it from https://www.pisymbol.net/

Comment: @crskhr that's just showing you how to get pi in html equivalent to using `\pi` in latex. It ins't even forcing the font so that link will appear differently to different people depending on the font defaults they have in their browser. Why do you want that exact font???????  if you go into the debugger (F12 in IE and edge) right menu inspect in chrome and firefox, you can check what fonts are being used in your browser but you should make font choices for the whole document not for individual letters.

Comment: Where have you taken your \pi picture?

Comment: See the 4th comment.

Comment: Look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479395/welcoming-2019-pi-day-how-to-draw-the-letter-%cf%80)

Answer (score 2):

You can load `Symbol.ttf` in LuaLaTeX 1.12:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{symbol-mt}{
  \EncodingSymbol{\textpi}{"70}
}

\newfontface\pifont{Symbol.ttf}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  NFSSEncoding=symbol-mt,
  Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\begin{document}
{\huge\pifont\textpi}
\end{document}
```

[image: Symbol sample]

The XeTeX renderer does not appear to be able to read this font

Answer (score 1):

Is this is the one you expect?

```
\documentclass{book}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{m}{up}{<->psyr}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{splpi}{U}{mtt}{m}{up}
\SetSymbolFont{splpi}{normal}{U}{mtt}{m}{up}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{splpi}{'160}

\begin{document}

\[
\pi
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: that's a pi, but not the same font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clearly, Mady wants to have his `\pi` and `\eta 2`.

Comment: I agree, it is definitely not the same pi.